# how to negate a statement in unix

Tags: unix

Hi all,

suppose I have a file with data 'abc','xyz','uvw','zzz'. We can fine any value from the file with grep command but how can we print all values except 'zzz'. What will be the command.

Thanks,
.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the data is on separate lines, it's just:

```
grep -v zzz
```

You can read all about it in the `man` page, which on my system states:

```
-v, --invert-match
      Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
```